# How to get position of turtles ? (turtle module python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm using turtle module and I want to get the position of turtles. I looked at the documentation, but maybe I just don't see it.

I would like to know if two turtles are at the same position, so a code like this :

```py
from turtle import *

turtle1 = Turtle()
turtle2 = Turtle()

pos1 = ... #Should be turtle1 position
pos2 = ... #SHould be turtle2 position
if pos1 == pos2:
    #do stuff
```

Comment: Found this in 4 seconds: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/turtle.html#turtle.position

Answer (score 0):

Since turtles crawl a floating point plane, an `==` (equal) comparison won't work well in the long run.  You want to get the *distance* between two turtles and decide how close together represents *same* for your application:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

turtle1 = Turtle()
turtle2 = Turtle()

if turtle1.distance(turtle2) < 5:  # pick distance that works for your app
    # do stuff
```